# How to install Erlang 18 with openssl 1.0.2k from source installtion

Tags: openssl, erlang, ejabberd

I am trying to install erlang 18 in centos 7 I have used otp_src_18.0 from erlang source  and installed the dependencies **gcc gcc-c++ make libxslt fop ncurses-devel *openjdk-devel unixODBC unixODBC-devel libyaml-devel openssl-devel expat-devel automake** and checked the openssl version in centos **OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017** but I am getting the following error with **./configure** command

---

**********************  APPLICATIONS DISABLED  **********************

---

crypto         : No usable OpenSSL found 
ssh            : No usable OpenSSL found 
ssl            : No usable OpenSSL found

---

---

**********************  APPLICATIONS INFORMATION  *******************

---

wx             : wxWidgets not found, wx will NOT be usable

---

Comment: I'd try installing `openssl-devel` as well. If that doesn't fix it, check if there are any relevant error messages in `lib/crypto/config.log`.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved:** configure with **--with-ssl** flag its solved the issue:

```sh
$ ./configure --with-ssl
```